# MongoDB TTL/ExpireAfterSeconds is misbehaving and not deleting all data after given time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

1) We have put expireAfterSeconds=15 on column of type: date

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_ts" : -1
        },
        "name" : "AnjaliIndex",
        "ns" : "test.sessions",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 15
    }
]
```

It is working fine on yesterdays date but is not working fine on todays date i.e it is removing data when i change document date from current date to yesterdays date where it should delete all data. (Current date which i given is even not future time but previous time)

Why is this happening? Is there any particular cycle or time when mongodb engine collect documents for expiry?

(I have seen related question but in that question use case is different where he was giving future date)

Mongo DB Version: 3.2.22

Sample Document:(not gettinkg deleted)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dde452818c87122389bbc09"),
    "authorization" : "a0ce0b43-194d-4402-99cb-b660b3365757",
    "userNumber" : "gourav@gmail.com",
    "_ts" : ISODate("2019-11-27T13:43:04.776Z")
}
```

Comment: what is the version of mongoDB you are using?

Comment: @Sohan: Version 3.2.22

Comment: Please post a sample document.

Comment: I think you are missing some create date on index that is userd by TTL to remove the documents.. You need to create index with date

Comment: @prasad_: Updated in description

Comment: @Sohan: Could you please give example, like in question the index json is there which gets created. Do i need to mention something else somewhere?

Comment: Before that , How did you create the index?  paste that code as well

Comment: Please type `ISODate()` in your shell and see what is it showing. Also see what is it showing with `Date()`.

Comment: @Sohan We are craeating using Robo 3T and just go in indexes and right click and create index

Comment: Did you check my solution below, it is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer and see if that can help you.

```
db.my_collection.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

After that, every document that you insert in this collection must have the "createdAt" with the current date:

```
db.myCollection.insert( {
   "createdAt": new Date(), // This can be set in UTC
   "dataExample": 2,
   "Message": "#### My data ####"
} )
```